# How to show full tilemap using phaser?

Tags: sprite, phaser-framework, tile, tiled

I have created tilemap using Tiled software of pixel size 1200x1000. While rendering it using phaser I have set width equal to 500 and height equal to 400.After this only map of 500x400 area is loading and remaining part is missing. How can I show the full map in 500x400 area on my webpage?

Comment: you have to scale now your world layer:   layer.scale.set(0.5); // scale to half   layer.resizeWorld();
https://phaser.io/examples/v2/tilemaps/resize-map

Comment: Thank you @episch. But what If I want to see the full map like How can I zoom out and zoom in so that I can be able to see the full map?

Comment: May you want use the fullsceen mode like  game.scale.fullScreenScaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.EXACT_FIT;

https://phaser.io/examples/v2/display/fullscreen

Comment: No, that will fit the map to the screen. I don't want that either. My question was that I have created a map of 1200X1000 size. Now I want to show that in a  scaled way may be .5 scaling. Is that possible?

Comment: having same issue... it is possible with `layer.scale.set(0.5);` and then resizing the world to the layer - `layer.resizeWorld();` this will work. But if you have objects layer they will not scale for example if you have a path to character to follow the path will not scale so it wont fit the new scaled map... cant find a way around it for now

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any other way to scale the every object inside the map along with map while loading map.